# Is it ok to use a dataset from public API for Final Year Project?

Tags: machine-learning, scraping

I am about to start a final year at my university and I want to do a Final Year Project based on Machine Learning.

I would like to learn basics of Machine Learning by utilising sci-kit.
My project may involve predicting prices for graphics cards depending either on sales of games or prices of bitcoin.

I read this [post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-illegal-is-it-to-get-data-from-a-100-accessible-but-not-exposed-api) and I understand that's generally illegal to get/scrap data from APIs without permission, but is it possible to get it and use it for 'fair-use' and 'non-profit' for my project?
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you ask the owners of the data? I imagine most would be OK with you using their data for a school project with their permission.

Comment: Scaring is not needed; there are lots of public sales datasets; e.g., [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data) or [that](https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting). Using them has the benefit of allowing you to compare your performance with others'. Welcome to the site and good luck!

Comment: @Emre Thanks Emre for the links. I hope I may find the dataset for what I am looking for, and that is prices of graphics cards. It's just I want to see if a given algorithm will manage to spot patterns for prices of graphics cards with bitcoin and/or prices exchange. for timleathart I will definitely try to ask but I feel I don't have enought time to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing one years ago, and I found the answer: "you can do it by specifying sources and writing that you assume all responsibility".
You have also to write that you wont use data in order to make money.

Comment: Is it possible for you to find out where you got this answer from? It's just I would like to use it as a reference if anything happens to me or my project. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a direct source. It's a common strategy for me and my university colleges.